# Angular 15 Material bug input on focus when using Tailwindcss

Tags: angular, angular-material, tailwind-css

Before focusing:

[image: Before focus]

After focusing:

[image: After focus]

Problem:

Using angular mat v. 15 and latest tailwindcss there is a bug when focusing input field.

To reproduce the problem:

```
ng new angular-test
cd angular-test
ng add @angular/material
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**styles.scss**

```
[...]

/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi">
</mat-form-field>
```

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

tailwind is adding border-style: solid; which is causing the extra border to be rendered

quick solution would be to override the right border style

add this in the styles.css file

```css
.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field .mdc-notched-outline__notch {
  border-right-style: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working for border, however, for the padding the issue still exists https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74621735/angular-material-15-with-tailwind-css-3-2-4-in-angular-project-mismatched

Comment: is also had to add this: .mat-mdc-input-element {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}