# Angular material 15 with Tailwind CSS 3.2.4 in Angular project mismatched

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I am using Angular 15 with Angular material 15, then I have added Tailwind CSS as per the instruction https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/angular

The material component design got mismatched as shown below

[image]

The placeholder name is truncated as it should be

[image]

The line appears in the text box.

In the style.scss

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Tailwind config

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
    ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: having same issue, did you get to solve it?

Comment: @add9 Nope I haven't found the solution till yet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74501000/649419 here is one solution worked for me

Comment: @add9 That seems to be working fine for the border, however, the padding for placeholder is not working.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the placeholder issue, can you post the HTML and any custom CSS you are using for the form field

Comment: I also had to add this: .mat-mdc-input-element {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

Answer (score 4):

You must add into your tailwind.config.js in module.exports the next config:

corePlugins: {
preflight: false
},

Using the above solution can cause some problems with tailwindcss classes. For this reason it is better to add the following lines in style.scss:

.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field .mdc-notched-outline__notch {
border-right-style: hidden;
}

Answer (score 1):

Tailwind by default adds a border on the right side of the items (something like that). Adding a border-style: none does solve this problem. You add the following code to your global styles file and it should work (at least it worked for me)

```
*, ::before, ::after {
  border-style: none;
}
```

- UPDATE

Following the above method would also remove all the border styles from your app.
Found the following solution which only effects the classes in mat-forms-field > mat-label

```
.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field
  .mdc-notched-outline__notch {
  border-right-style: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with tailwind applying border-style: 'solid' to everything.

```
*, ::before, ::after {
  border-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Not working, it creates a space at the border.

Comment: I just had the exact same problem in a new project with angular 15.1.0 and tailwind 3.2.6 and the above code fixed the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

these all the styles I use to fix the material / tailwind combo:

```
//*******************************
//** Material / tailwind fixes **
//*******************************
.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field
  .mdc-notched-outline__notch {
  border-right-style: hidden;
}

.mat-mdc-input-element {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky !important;
}

[type='text'],
[type='email'],
[type='url'],
[type='password'],
[type='number'],
[type='date'],
[type='datetime-local'],
[type='month'],
[type='search'],
[type='tel'],
[type='time'],
[type='week'],
[multiple],
textarea,
select {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually by just adding:

```
corePlugins: { preflight: false },
```

Works.... below my full tailwind config:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,ts}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
  corePlugins: { preflight: false },
};
```

Thanks to [Yorguin Augusto Lopez Ortiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20996277/yorguin-augusto-lopez-ortiz)